# Why would WooCommerce's REST API respond with a 302 on authenticated calls?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

So I am integrating with a woocommerce store via the WooCommerce API.

Sometimes, the api endpoint responds as expected, with a JSON payload containing relevant resource data. Sometimes, it responds with a 302 error and a redirect location.

When it redirects, the location looks like this: https://example.com?aiowpsec_do_log_out=1&al_additional_data=1&_wpnonce=861898d6ac

I assumed this may be an issue with the permalinks, but they are already set up as custom and not the default setting which many articles warn about.

The interesting behaviour though, is that if I make an API request without credentials the API still responds as expected. And, if I go to the permalinks page and save the settings, the API then starts working as expected for a short duration. If I clear cookies, it still performs the same.

Any idea what may be causing this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

We ended up changing the permalinks within the wordpress settings and this solved the issue for us.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).